# How to separate routes with trie-route for koajs?

Tags: node.js, routes, koa2

How do I separate routes with [trie-route](https://github.com/koajs/trie-router) for koajs?

app.js:

```
const Koa = require('koa')
const get = require('./routes/get')
const post = require('./routes/post')

const app = new Koa()

app.use(get)
app.use(post)
app.listen(3000)
```

routes/get.js:

```
'use strict'

const Router = require('koa-trie-router')

const router = new Router()

// middleware that is specific to this router
router.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  console.log('Time: ', Date.now())
  await next()
})

// define the home page route
router.get('/', async (ctx, next) => {
  ctx.type = 'json'
  ctx.body = {
    message: 'Birds home page'
  }
})

// Separate this post route in a new file.
// router.post('/', async (ctx, next) => {
//   ctx.type = 'json'
//   ctx.body = {
//     message: 'Post birds home page'
//   }
// })

module.exports = router.middleware()
```

routes/post.js:

```
'use strict'

const Router = require('koa-trie-router')

const router = new Router()

router.post('/', async (ctx, next) => {
  ctx.type = 'json'
  ctx.body = {
    message: 'Post birds home page'
  }
})

module.exports = router.middleware()
```

When I try to post it on my Postman at `http://127.0.1.1:3000/`:

```
Method Not Allowed
```

Any ideas how can I get around to this?

My package.js:

```
{
  "name": "basic",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "basic sample",
  "main": "app.js",
  "author": "xxx",
  "license": "BSD-2-Clause",
  "dependencies": {
    "koa": "^2.3.0",
    "koa-trie-router": "^2.1.5"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "kao",
    "nodejs"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You sure that's the host the app is listening on? Shouldn't that be `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're seeing is due to the first call to `app.use()` taking precedence over the next one. For example, if I do the following instead:

```
app.use(post)
app.use(get)
```

Then I get the same error but on the `GET` request. To get this to work, what I did was to return the actual router from `routes/get.js` and `routes/post.js`, and then configure the middleware in `app.js`.

So in your `routes/get.js` and `routes/post.js` -

Instead of:

```
module.exports = router.middleware()
```

Export:

```
module.exports = router
```

In `app.js`:

```
const Koa = require('koa')
const get = require('./routes/get')
const post = require('./routes/post')

const Router = require('koa-trie-router')

const router = new Router()

router.get(get.middleware());
router.post(post.middleware());

const app = new Koa()
app.use(router.middleware());
app.listen(3000)
```